# Reflection instead of Factory pattern?

Tags: java, reflection, factory

Here is how I managed to constructor objects at runtime based on the subclass I want to invoke (to avoid having to update a Factory class every time I want to add a new subclass):

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Main{
    
    private static final class X{}
    
    private static abstract class A{
        
        public A(X x){}
        
        public static A newInstance(Class<? extends A> subType, X x) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
            
            return subType.getConstructor(X.class).newInstance(x);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private static final class A_1 extends A{
        
        public A_1(X x){
            
            super(x);
            //...
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            X x = new X();
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            A a = A.newInstance(A_1.class, x);
            t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

At first I thought it would be slow but I'm getting 1ms for the first iteration and 0 for any consecutive instantiation.

Can I expect a similar behavior once my application is deployed (Here I simplified the process but it's hardly any harder in the context of my application).

What are the pros and cons of doing such a technique?

Comment: A full millisecond is actually a pretty long time.  You'd probably want to measure in nanoseconds.

Comment: Con: no compile-time checking for the existence of a matching constructor for `A_1`.  Con: the reflected constructor's parameter type must be exactly `X` (not merely a type compatible with `X`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection is almost always the worst way to do things.

- Reflection is slow.  It usually cannot be optimized at runtime by the just-in-time compiler.
- Reflection is bug prone.  The compiler cannot verify correctness of reflection code.  In your case, the compiler can’t guarantee that `subType` has a constructor which takes a single X argument.
- Reflection is hard to follow in code and thus hard to maintain.

In your case, you want a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) that represents the subclass constructor:

```
public static A newInstance(Function<? super X, ? extends A> constructor, X x) {
        
    return constructor.apply(x);
}
```

You would call that method with a method reference:

```
A a = newInstance(A_1::new, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, reflection is not the base case (but it definitely works). I offer to use `Factory` to hold all factories methods to create required types. Just add the ability to add new factories to the implementation without changing it.

I offer a solution without changing your main API `public static <T extends Base> T newInstance(Class<T> subType, X x)`.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Factory.add(OneBase.class, OneBase::new);
        Factory.add(TwoBase.class, TwoBase::new);

        OneBase oneBase = Factory.newInstance(OneBase.class, new X());
        TwoBase twoBase = Factory.newInstance(TwoBase.class, new X());
    }

}

final class Factory {

    private static final Map<Class<? extends Base>, Function<X, ? extends Base>> FACTORIES = new HashMap<>();

    public static void add(Class<? extends Base> subType, Function<X, ? extends Base> factory) {
        FACTORIES.put(subType, factory);
    }

    public static <T extends Base> T newInstance(Class<T> subType, X x) {
        return (T)FACTORIES.get(subType).apply(x);
    }

}

final class X {}

abstract class Base {

    protected Base(X x) {}

}

final class OneBase extends Base {

    public OneBase(X x) {
        super(x);
    }

}

final class TwoBase extends Base {

    public TwoBase(X x) {
        super(x);
    }

}
```